# PHP Login and logout on same page causing error

Tags: php, authentication, logout

I'm making a webpage, and i'm trying to make it so that a page shows a login field when you are not logged in, and shows a log out button when you are logged in.
The log in and log out work fine on their own, because i used them first on seperate webpages, but now, on the same page, once you are logged in, you cannot log out anymore, and i have no idea why, i thought it may had something to do with $_POST but after a bit of testing it seems to have nothing to do with it.

Code for displaying on the same webpage:

```
function DisplayLogin(){

    if (isLoggedIn()){
        DisplayLoggedIn();
    } else {
        DisplayLoginForm();
    }
}

function DisplayLoginForm(){
    echo "<div>";
    include_once 'Login.php';
    echo "</div>";      
}

function DisplayLoggedIn(){
    echo "<div>";
    include_once 'Logout.php';
    echo "</div>";  
}
```

Code for loggin in:

```
<?PHP
 function Login($UserName, $Password){
        if (isPasswordCorrect($UserName, $Password)) {
            sec_session_start();
            $_SESSION['LoggedIn'] = true;
            $_SESSION['UserName'] = $UserName;
            $_SESSION['UserID'] = getUserID($UserName);
            $headerstring = determineHeader();
            $_SESSION['TimeStamp'] = time();
            header($headerstring);
            unset($_SESSION['LoginURL']);
        } else {
            echo 'Username or Password incorrect';
        }
    }
  if (isset($_POST["Login"])) {
        Login($_POST['UserName'], $_POST['Password']);
    }

?>

<form method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="UserName">
    <input type="password" name="Password">
    <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Log In">
</form>
```

Code for logging out:

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
        session_unset();
        session_destroy();
        //header("Refresh:0");
    }

?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="submit" name="logout" value="Logout">
</form>
```

NOTE: code syntax is not completely correct because i deleted some unimportant stuff.

EDIT: I'm pretty sure the page is logging the user back in after pressing the logout button, but i don't know why or how.

EDIT: isLoggedIn code:

```
function isLoggedIn(){
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    sec_session_start();
}
if (isset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']) && $_SESSION['LoggedIn']) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;

}
}
```

EDIT: password code:

```
function isPasswordCorrect($UserName, $Password){
        $mysqli = connectToDatabase();
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT UserPassword, UserID FROM users  WHERE UserName=?");
        $stmt->bindParam("1", $UserName);
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $stmt->fetch();
        return (password_verify($Password, $row['UserPassword']));
    }
```

EDIT: putting "exit;" at the and of the if and else part of the DisplayLogin() function fixes the problem, but this is not an acceptable solution as this prevents the rest of the page loading.

Comment: Is the logout form showing ?

Comment: Yes it is, you can click the button, and when i look at right after the button press, it seems you are logged out, but for some reason, you are not

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    sec_session_start();
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    //header("Refresh:0");
}
```

You've missed to start the secure session before you unset it.

Comment: It is started, because before that form is loaded, DisplayLogin check wether or not the user is logged in, and that starts a session

Comment: Just looked like maybe it wasn't, since you were starting it in Login - Try $_SESSION = array(); instead og session_unset();

Comment: Doesn't make a difference :/ but the log out works fine, it's only when combined with the login on the same page it acts weird, i have the feeling it logs you in, but i have no idea why

Comment: Try add this: // get session parameters $params = session_get_cookie_params(); // Delete the actual cookie. setcookie(session_name(), '', time() - 42000, $params["path"], $params["domain"], $params["secure"], $params["httponly"]);

Comment: Doesn't make a difference either :/

Comment: Please post your isPasswordCorrect function :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?PHP
if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    unset($_SESSION['LoggedIn']);
    unset($_SESSION['UserName']);
    unset($_SESSION['UserID']);
    unset($_SESSION['TimeStamp']);
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
    //header("Refresh:0");
}

?>
```

Try to unset all Sessions.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference :/

Comment: @Midasso would you like to change. `sec_session_start();` to `session_start();` ?

Comment: currently all that sec_session_start() does is session_start(), so that won't make a difference

Comment: @Midasso would you like to remove this condition? `if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    sec_session_start();
}`

Comment: why? i don't understand how that could cause a problem? It just starts a session when there is none started?

Comment: @Midasso can you try? after that I will explain.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, but i don't know why it didn't work before. 
In the page where i was calling displayLogin(), i called isLoggedIn() after it, for some reason this let the session remain as it was before the logout, but by storing the result of isLoggedIn()  in a variable and using the variable, before calling displayLogin(), everything works as it should.

I just don't know why it didn't work before, can anyone explain that to me?